# Firefox is crashing on http request using addon

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying this code:

```
// This is an active module of the goelvivek (10) Add-on
// This is an active module of the goelvivek (9) Add-on

var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var request = require('request');
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "end",
  contentScript: 'var doc_c=document.title;console.log(doc_c);var body_uri=document.URI;self.postMessage(body_uri);',  
   onAttach:function(body_c){
       console.log("onattach");
       var req = request.Request({
           url:"http://google.com",
           content:{
               v:"1",
               body:body_c               
               },
               oncomplete: function (response){
                   console.log(response);
                   }
       });
       req.get();
       } 
});
```

but Firefox is crashing. Why?

you can test addon at https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1021520/latest/

Comment: Did you send a crash report? See http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20crashes#w_get-help-fixing-this-crash

Comment: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/bp-1f78c671-cc54-4fc9-86f8-b80022111019

Comment: but I am getting error 

We couldn't find the OOID you're after. If you recently submitted this crash, it may still be in the queue.

If you belive this message is an error, please submit a Bugzilla ticket describing what happened, and please include the URL for this page.

Comment: but I am not getting why this code will make browser to be crashed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not crashing for me on a recent Nightly. Instead it consumes a lot of memory and hangs until an Unresponsive script dialog shows up.

The reason for the hang is that you expected the `body_c` parameter of `onAttach` to be the message from the content script, but it is a [worker object](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html) with lots of subreferences, possibly even with circular ones.

The SDK's `Request` has this [code](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blame/master/packages/addon-kit/lib/request.js#LID174) to convert an object passed as `content` to a string before sending into request. It's supposed to walk the object recursively and apparently it chokes on the worker object you passed in.

Comment: Only one thing to be added: instead of trying to send the `onAttach` parameter this extension should call `worker.on("message", function(data) {...})` there as indicated in the second "Communicating With Content Scripts" example. That callback will actually receive the message from the content script then.